# 2 select menu filters with Jquery disable, pass values to one function

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, function

I have 2 select menus whose values i want to get passed to a function.
I am trying to use jquery to disabled the 2nd select until the first one is selected.

I am having 2 issues with this:

- My jquery does not seem to want to disable the 2nd select menu.
- Also how can i pass the 1st select menu value to the onchange
  function value in the second select menu.

Thanks in advance

**Function**

```
function showlog(str, username) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "getlog.php?username=" + username + "&q=" + str, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var linkOrder = [
        "employee_user",
        "acyear"
        ];
    $('select.linked').not('#' + linkOrder[0]).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('.linked').change(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var index = $.inArray(id, linkOrder);
        $('#' + linkOrder[index + 1]).removeAttr('disabled');
    });
});
```

**FORM**

```
    <form>
<select id="employee_user" name="employee_user" class="linked">
        <option value="">Select</option>
    </select>

    <select id="acyear" name="acyear" onchange="showlog(this.value, 1st select value" class="linked">
    <option value=""></option>
    </select>
    </form>
```

Comment: I am confused with showUser() and showlog() function. you have defined showlog() and you are calling showUser()

Comment: Sorry was in a rush, My bad. Question updated

Comment: Found a better solution here: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained Do you know how to do this part of my question? - showlog(this.value, 1st select value